# Handle java.net.SocketException: Socket closed when multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server

I'm doing a school project where we are supposed to create a simplefied Hotel booking system and then use it with a server/client communication.
Since I wanted to push the project a bit and do a multithreaded program, I've got a Socket Exception that I'm not sure how to handle. I've searched everywhere for an answer and I know that the exception occours because I'm trying to use a socket that has been closed. But from what I've read on Oracle-docs, their example is doing that as well.

So, is this actually Ok, just that I need to handle the exception? Cause my code runs fine, I just see the exceptions since I've put e.printStackTrace(); in my catch.

My Client class:

```
package client;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 6066);

            //System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

            OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

            InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);

            LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
            String date = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyy/MM/dd").format(localDate);

            System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            System.out.print("Namn: ");
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Ålder: ");
            String age = sc.nextLine();

            out.writeUTF(name);
            out.writeUTF(age);
            out.writeUTF(date);

            System.out.println(in.readUTF());


            client.close();
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And my Server class:

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;


public class Server {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

        int port = 6066;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Listening for client..");

            try {

                Socket connectedClient = server.accept();
                ClientHandle ch = new ClientHandle(connectedClient);
                Thread t = new Thread((Runnable) ch);
                t.start();

            }catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then my ClientHandle class which has the run() for the server-side:

```
package server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import resources.*;

public class ClientHandle implements Runnable{

    Socket connectedClient;
    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;

    public ClientHandle(Socket connectedClient) {
        this.connectedClient = connectedClient;
        try{
            this.in = new DataInputStream(this.connectedClient.getInputStream());
            this.out = new DataOutputStream(this.connectedClient.getOutputStream());
        }catch(IOException ex) {

        }
    }

    Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
    Ticket yourTicket = new Ticket();
    Server server = new Server();

    @Override
    public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {

                    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                    System.out.println("Client " + host + " has connected.");

                    out.writeUTF("Välkommen till Hotel Gisslevik!\nVänligen fyll i nedan information för att slutföra din bokning.\n");

                    String yourName = in.readUTF();
                    String age = in.readUTF();
                    int yourAge = Integer.parseInt(age);

                    String date = in.readUTF();
                    yourTicket.setDate(date);

                    Person guest = new Person(yourName, yourAge);
                    hotel.setRooms();
                    Integer room = hotel.getRoom();
                    String rent = "J";

                    if (rent.indexOf("J") >= 0) {
                        yourTicket.setId(yourName);
                        if (hotel.checkIn(guest, room, yourTicket.getId(), yourTicket.getDate())) {
                            String yourId = yourTicket.getId();
                            out.writeUTF("\nDitt rum är nu bokat den " + date + ". \nBokningsnummer: " + yourId);
                        }
                    }

                    out.flush();
                    connectedClient.close();


                }catch (EOFException e) {


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

If I just comment e.printStackTrace(); the exceptions doesn't show, but I would like to know how to handle them (if they should be handled). I've been searching the internet for days and checked out tutorials, but I don't find a proper answer to this.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: @Pavel Pointless edit rejected.

Answer (score 2):

> Handle java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Don't close the socket and then continue to use it.

> when multithreading?

Irrelevant.

You have `connectedClient.close()` inside your `while (true)` loop. Solution: move it outside.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even think of that. Thank you! Is it safe to ignore the java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error that appers instead?

Comment: No, it isn't. That indicates a completely different error. Look up 'Official reasons for Software caused connection abort: socket write error' here.